# Why does plotly.Mesh3d refuse to plot a 3D function?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am attempting to plot the analytical t=0 solution to the 3D wave equation:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

f = lambda x, y, z: np.sin(x) * np.sin(y) * np.sin(z)
x = np.linspace(-5, 5)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5)
z = np.linspace(-5, 5)

Z = f(x, y, z)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=Z)])
fig.show()
```

This, however, outputs an empty graph. I am not sure why.

I originally considered that the issue may simply be that 3D plots of 3D functions are impossible, but I believe that not to be the case, given that many 3D functions can be plotted just fine as a 3D mesh. For instance, the probability density of the hydrogen wavefunction `psi_nlm(r, theta, phi)` can be plotted without issue using `Mesh3d`. In addition, `Mesh3d()` takes in 3 arguments by default, so it is supposed to be used for 3D functions and shouldn't be restricted to 2D functions. So what is the issue?

Comment: I am not that familiar with 3d mesh plots, but I believe the (x,y,z) coordinates have to be in the right order such that triangles can be drawn between subsequent coordinates to form a surface